# Is it possible to upgrade polymer 3 partially?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to upgrade my application from polymer 2 to polymer 3. I tried thru modulizer but application got broken. It is big size application, so I'm planning to upgrade elements one by one. Is it possible to upgrade some part of application(elements) to polymer 3.

I converted one of my application element as per polymer 3 syntax and then tried to import that into another element like below but it is not working.

See the below sample example,

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.js';
import '@polymer/paper-checkbox/';
import { setPassiveTouchGestures } from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/settings';

class StartPolymer3 extends PolymerElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      message: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ready(){
    super.ready();
  }

  static get template () {
    return html`
      <style>
        paper-checkbox {
          --paper-checkbox-checked-ink-color: #FFFFFF;
          --paper-checkbox-unchecked-ink-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
      </style>
      <h1>Start Polymer 3.0</h1>
      <p>[[message]]</p>
      <paper-checkbox id="omgpie">I like pie.</paper-checkbox>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('start-polymer3', StartPolymer3);
```

Here StartPolymer3 element converted as polymer 3 element, now I should I use this inside another element which is wrote in polymer 2. I tried like below inside polymer2 element but its not working.

```
 <script type="module">
   import { StartPolymer3 } from '../views/start-polymer3.js';
</script>

<start-polymer3 message="testHello"></start-polymer3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Polymer 3.0 API is almost 100% backward compatible with Polymer 2.x—the only changes are removing APIs related to HTML Imports (such as importHref), and converting Polymer's API to be module-based rather than globals-based.
Here related [link](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/about_30#api-changes)

Comment: i am getting below errors  on imports ``Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`` i am not using polymer serve to complie instead we use run application ``node index.html``is it possible to fix this issue without using polymer serve/build

Comment: I am not sure but you may set a base path of app  adding into index.html something like:  ` <base href="./">`